# How to render and redirect together in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on ExpressJS to build my website's backend and it calls my API to create a response.
However I need to show that payment was successful and then redirect automatically redirect after the a resource has been created on AWS. I am using websockets for this as this takes some time to happen.
But when I use res.render(),then call the API and if status is 200 use res.redirect() to go to another page. But when I do this I get this error:

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
> to the client
> at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:370:5)
> at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:573:11)

I know the error is because I am calling res.redirect() after res.render(), but I don't know any other solution to my problem.

Could someone please tell me how to do this?

Code snippet:

```
res.render('success.ejs')

console.log("Calling websocket endpoint: ", wsData)

aws.websocketHandler(ws_data)
    .then(async (resp_data) => {
        let data = await resp_data;
        console.log("Status: ", data.status_code)
        if (data.status_code === 200) {
            return data
        }
    }).then((data)=>{
        console.log(data)
        res.redirect("/dashboard")
})
```

What other approach can I take?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you just manually set a status code, a `Location` header and a body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know the problem so i'll just provide an alternative.
Instead of using `res.redirect`, you can just emit a JSON response and handle it from the client's side. For example,

```
     ...

     }).then((data)=>{
        console.log(data)
        //res.redirect("/dashboard") is now commented
        let json_data = {redirect_url:"/dashboard"}
        client.emit('redirect',json_data)
    })
```

Then on the client side, you write,

```
    socket.on("redirect",(data)=>{
        let location = data.redirect_url
        // write function to notify user of redirect
        setInterval(()=>{
            window.location.replace(location)
        },3000)
    })
```